# how to get the title of workbook from openpyxl python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have this code to prompt user to get an Excel file

```
drawinglist = askopenfile(parent=self, title='Choose the file', mode='rb', filetypes=[("Excel file", "*.xlsx")])
```

It consists of 2 columns & X amount of rows depend on cases.
Then I want to write into column 3, if some value is found in column 1.

```
maxrow = sheet.max_row 
for item in somelist:
    mdwg, mrev = item.split("_rev")
    for rownum in range(1, maxrow):
        rowdwg = sheet.cell(row=rownum, column=1).value
        if rowdwg == mdwg:
            sheet.cell(row=rownum, column=3).value = "Not found"
```

Then I need to save the workbook. But this code:

```
wb.save()
```

requires the file name to be passed into as argument.
How do I know the file name when it can be any file open by user?

Comment: You may want to complete the code first and run it at least once yourself, then the answer most likely will come to you. If you want to check what the first line does: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html

Comment: <_io.BufferedReader name='C:/.../File.xlsx'>
if i print(drawinglist), it gives me this. but how can i use this?

Comment: The print confirms the information about the file is there. You may want to google what kind of object drawinglist is and which attributes are available for it.

Comment: The attribute is there, 'name=' so filename (and the path to) is in 'drawinglist.name'

Comment: @moken, thanks! it works. Can you point me to the doc that mentioned this info? cant find it in the link from the first comment here.

Comment: BufferedReader is a class of the IO (input/output) module. Perhaps this link will help https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.FileIO.name

Comment: In the link of the first comment, just below the examples of the function is written: “ The above two functions create an Open dialog and return the opened file object(s) in read-only mode.”; a few lines further down there is an alternative function returning the filename (w/o opening the file). I was hoping OP will figure it out with the result from the print() and some googling. Nevermind. Good luck!